# nav bar does not show up in ie9

Tags: html, css

I am not able to see my top nav bar in ie9 browsers....
its showing in my local machine...
but its not showing up in the server can you please say how to fix it....

not working here

providing my code below

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
      <div class="navbar-inner">
        <div class="container" style="width: 1153px;">
          <a class="btn btn-navbar collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </a>
          <a class="brand" href="http://v2.defie.co/" style="padding-top: 0px;">
            <img alt="change" class="defieLogo" src="http://www.defie.co/designerImages/defie_logo_only.png">
          </a>
          <div class="nav-collapse collapse" style="height: 0px;">
            <ul class="nav" style="padding-left: 312px;"> 

              <li class="active"><a href="http://v2.defie.co/product.html">Product</a></li>
              <li><a href="http://v2.defie.co/solution.html">Solutions</a></li>
              <li><a href="http://v2.defie.co/service.html">Services</a></li>
              <li class="iphonePartnerLink"><a href="http://v2.defie.co/partner.html">Partners</a></li>
              <li class="iphoneContactLink"><a href="http://v2.defie.co/contact.html">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>

            <ul class="nav" id="navSecond">
              <li class=""><a href="/docs/examples/partners.html">Partners</a></li>
              <li><a href="/docs/examples/contact.html">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
            <!--<form method="post" class="navbar-form pull-right" action="http://intra.defie.co/Account/">
              <input class="span2" type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email">
              <input class="span2" type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password">
              <button type="submit" class="btn">Sign in</button>
            </form>-->


             <a href="#myModal" role="button" class="btn" data-toggle="modal">Login</a>
             <a href="#myModal" role="button" class="btn" data-toggle="modal" style="margin-left: 20px;">SIGN UP</a>



          </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: (Uninstall IE, install real browser.) Is it Bootstrap? Could you provide the css code for it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `bootstrap.css` you have a Microsoft Filter there by default, you need to look at the `.navbar-inner` selector in your CSS and remove this:

```
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#333333',endcolorstr='#222222',GradientType=0)
```

Its a black gradient being shown over your menu, just remove that from your bootstrap.css file and the nav menu will appear as expected.